# How can I change the persistence message that shows when a customer logs out?

Tags: cookie, header, toplinks, persistent

I am trying to change the persistence message that shows in the header when a customer logs out.

```
(Not Mr Foo?)
```

I've tried changing it via translation file:

```
"Not %s?","Log In / Register"
```

I've also tried rewriting the block class:

```
class Mycompany_Persistent_Block_Header_Additional extends Mage_Persistent_Block_Header_Additional
{
    /**
     * Render additional header html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $text = $this->__('Log In / Register');

        $this->setAnchorText($text);
        $this->setHref($this->getUrl('persistent/index/unsetCookie'));

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

The above doesn't have an effect on changing the link as it still displays as if the rewrite doesn't exist even though I can see the my class is being loaded.

Has anyone managed to change this bit of text? All i want to do is replace it with `Log In / Register`

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason that the rewrite does not work even though your class is being call is because you call your change and then still call the original function.

If you remove the call to the `parent::_toHtml()` then you should have the system working as desired. I think you still need to call the later _toHtml functions in this case though.

```
class Mycompany_Persistent_Block_Header_Additional extends Mage_Persistent_Block_Header_Additional
{
    /**
     * Render additional header html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $text = $this->__('Log In / Register');

        $this->setAnchorText($text);
        $this->setHref($this->getUrl('persistent/index/unsetCookie'));
    }
}
```

I would suggest going with the changing of the translation if possible. I think the string you need would look as follows.

```
"(Not %s?)","Log In / Register"
```